# C/C++: How should preprocessor directive work on macros argument list?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, standards, preprocessor

Both C and C++ standards specify the following:

> 16.3.1 Argument substitution (C++11)
>
> 6.10.3.1 Argument substitution (C11)
>
> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded by a # or ## preprocessing token or followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

One can interpret this paragraph as if the standards require to:

(1) At first identify macro arguments (comma separated) and then expand all the macros contained in each argument separately,

or

(2) Expand all the macros contained in the argument list and then identify each argument.

To illustrate this, let's consider this sample code:

```
#define CONDITION (0)

#if (CONDITION > 0)
#define FunctionAlias(par_a, par_b, par_opt, par_c) \
          FunctionName(par_a, par_b, par_opt, par_c)
#else
#define FunctionAlias(par_a, par_b, par_c) \
          FunctionName(par_a, par_b, par_c)
#endif

int global_a, global_b, global_c;
#if (CONDITION > 0)
int global_opt;
#endif

void FunctionName(int a, int b, int c)
{
}
 
void AnotherFunction()
{
   FunctionAlias(
                  global_a,
                  global_b,
                  #if (CONDITION > 0)
                  global_opt,
                  #endif
                  global_c
                );
}
```

(1) Approach one would produce invalid code:

```
int global_a, global_b, global_c;

void FunctionName(int a, int b, int c)
{
}

void AnotherFunction()
{
  FunctionName(global_a, global_b, #if ((0) > 0) global_opt);
}
```

(2) Approach 2 produces valid C code:

```
int global_a, global_b, global_c;

void FunctionName(int a, int b, int c)
{
}

void AnotherFunction()
{
   FunctionName(global_a, global_b, global_c);
}
```

Which of the interpretations of the standards is the correct one?

Comment: I present to you a third interpretation: `error: embedding a directive within macro arguments has undefined behavior`. This is what GCC & Clang do. The error happens before the macro is expanded.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, done.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually, GCC 9.3.0 is compiling this code without a complain. Anyway, thanks for your comment - I rephrased the title to be more accurate.

Comment: Add `-pedantic-errors`, it makes GCC more standard-conformant.

Comment: You are right, thanks. Should this be interpreted as undefined behavior? The standard wording is vague to me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `-pedantic-errors` is dangerous for the same reason `-Werror` is dangerous. The official invocation for GCC's conformant mode is `-std=cNN -Wall -Wpedantic` where NN is the version of the C standard you want.  Leave _any_ of those options out and it's not fully conformant.

Comment: (Historical note: Some versions of GCC, circa 3.0, did make this particular case of UB a hard error.  I don't remember if it ever made it into a release that way, but we got _so many complaints_ from people who were annoyed at us breaking their code ... because they were putting `#ifdef`s inside the arguments to `printf`, and some C libraries make `printf` a macro.  So we backed it down to a warning.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you cannot, at all, put preprocessing directives inside the arguments to a function-like macro, because of some text a little down from what you quoted:

> If there are sequences of preprocessing tokens within the list of arguments that would otherwise act as preprocessing directives, the behavior is undefined.

[[N1570, §6.10.3 p11](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p11)].

Second, independent of that, the standard requires the behavior you called (1).  This is specified by this part of the text you quoted:

> Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

This sentence wouldn't make any sense if the arguments to a function-like macro were expanded before the boundaries between arguments were identified.  You can also see this by experiment, with a slight modification of your code:

```c
#if (CONDITION > 0)
#define FunctionAlias(par_a, par_b, par_opt, par_c) \
          FunctionName(par_a, par_b, par_opt, par_c)
#else
#define FunctionAlias(par_a, par_b, par_c) \
          FunctionName(par_a, par_b, par_c)
#endif

int global_a, global_b, global_c;
#if (CONDITION > 0)
int global_opt;
#define GLOBAL_OPT global_opt,
#else
#define GLOBAL_OPT /*nothing*/
#endif

void FunctionName(int a, int b, 
#if CONDITION > 0
                  int opt,
#endif
                  int c)
{
}
 
void AnotherFunction()
{
   FunctionAlias(
                  global_a,
                  global_b,
                  GLOBAL_OPT
                  global_c
                );
}
```

This will compile fine if `CONDITION` is not defined or zero, but when `CONDITION` is nonzero, you will get an error along the lines of

```
test.c: In function ‘AnotherFunction’:
test.c:28:17: error: macro "FunctionAlias" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
   28 |                 );
      |                 ^
```

demonstrating that `GLOBAL_OPT` was *not* expanded before looking for the four arguments to `FunctionAlias`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the answer. The interesting thing is that gcc -std=c11 (gcc 9.3.0) applies option (2).

Comment: @mrm It sure doesn't for me -- that's GCC's error message I pasted in there.

Answer (score 1):

> *After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the
> replacement list, unless preceded by a # or ## preprocessing token or
> followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the
> corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been
> expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing
> tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the
> preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.*
>
> One can interpret this paragraph as if the standard required to:
>
> (1) At first identify macro arguments (comma separated) and then
> expand all the macros contained in each argument separately,
>
> or
>
> (2) Expand all the macros contained in the argument list and then
> identify each argument.

I sort of see where you're coming from, but I don't really follow how you arrive at (2) as a plausible interpretation of the text.  The section you've quoted starts by specifying that argument substitution takes place "**After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution takes place**", and everything else is a description of what argument substitution entails. That includes the arguments being prepared for actual substitution by, under most circumstances, macro-expanding them.  (1) is the correct interpretation.

Do note, however, that macro expansion is an iterative process.  Speaking roughly, macro expansions are *rescanned* for further macro replacement, including the expansions of macro arguments performed as described in the quoted text.  This is why it is important that each argument's preprocessing tokens are expanded "as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file".  That isolates each one not just from the source text surrounding the host macro invocation but most importantly from the other arguments and their expansions.

<s>Note also that you could have tested this for yourself if you found the standard unclear.  You even produced your test case already.</s> On second thought, you *did not* provide a valid test case, because preprocessor directives may not appear in the argument list of a macro invocation.  The standard therefore has nothing to say about the result of preprocessing your example source.

Comment: The thing is I did the test myself and gcc -std=c11 gives no error. Whatsmore, it applies approach (2).

Comment: The fact that a particular compiler processes a construct a certain way does not imply anything about what the Standard actually requires, nor whether other compilers--including future versions of that same compiler--should be expected to behave likewise.

Comment: @mrn, Looking more closely at your example code, I find that (a) it is non-conforming as a result of containing preprocessor directives in the argument list of your macro invocation, and (b) your conclusion about the implications of interpretations (1) and (2) on the example code appears to conflate conditional inclusion processing with macro expansion.  Conditional inclusion and macro expansion are both activities performed by the preprocessor, but neither implies or subsumes the other.