# C++ Preprocessor Stringize - Different between GCC and MSVC

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

With the following example, the output is different between MSVC and GCC.  Can someone please point me in the right direction to understand why?

```
#define TO_STRING(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define QUOTE(...) TO_STRING(__VA_ARGS__)

#define KEY1 "Key1"
#define KEY2 "Key2"
#define KEY3 "Key3"
#define LEN1 32
#define LEN2 32


const char * cNVKeysMetaData = QUOTE(
{
    "Area1":[ 
        {
            "key":KEY1,
            "maxLength":LEN1,
            "type":"s",
            "default":"Hello"
        },
#if defined(TEST)
        {
            "key":KEY2,
            "maxLength":LEN2,
            "type":"s",
            "default":"invalid"
        },
#endif
        {
            "key":KEY3,
            "maxLength":64,
            "type":"s",
            "default":"invalid"
        }
    ]
}
);

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << cNVKeysMetaData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

GCC Output:

```
{ "Area1":[ { "key":"Key1", "maxLength":32, "type":"s", "default":"Hello" }, { "key":"Key3", "maxLength":64, "type":"s", "default":"invalid" } ] }
```

MSVC Output:

```
{ "Area1":[ { "key":"Key1", "maxLength":32, "type":"s", "default":"Hello" }, #if defined(TEST) { "key":"Key2", "maxLength":32, "type":"s", "default":"invalid" }, #endif { "key":"Key3", "maxLength":64, "type":"s", "default":"invalid" } ] }
```

Note that MSVC does replace the macros KEY1 etc, but does not strip out the #if.  GCC does strip out the #if.

Comment: @Peter, this is a completely reproducible example!  Paste it directly into godbolt.org and select either latest GCC or MSVC compiler.  All the macro definitions are included.

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what you mean. This is an mre https://godbolt.org/z/a6hYPh9ax

Comment: Thanks @cigien.  Just a note to others in the above example that the /E flag prevents compilation so need to remove it to see the compiled output.

Comment: I thought all the C++ boffins would be on top of this by now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [C/C++: How should preprocessor directive work on macros argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452244/c-c-how-should-preprocessor-directive-work-on-macros-argument-list) , you can't put preprocessor directives (like `#if`) inside macro argument lists. The behavior of your code is undefined.

I think I would do:

```
#ifdef TEST
#define IF_TEST(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define IF_TEST(...)
#endif

QUOTE(
 ....
 IF_TEST(
        {
            "key":KEY2,
            "maxLength":LEN2,
            "type":"s",
            "default":"invalid"
        },
  )
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good suggestion.  Fortunately in my case I don't have many different tests to do in the actual application (a very large file), so this is a suitable solution in practice.